# Show react reducer actions like redux devTool

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-reducer

I've created a `reducer` function using Reat's `useReducer` hook.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'increment':
            return { count: state.count + action.payload };
        case 'decrement':
            return { count: state.count - action.payload };
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}
```

And inside a component-

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {count: 0});
```

Now, I am dispatching an action after loading an API data like-

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const res = await fetch(some_url);
    const data = await res.json();
    dispatch({type: 'increment', payload: data});
  )();
})
```

**Now is there any way to check if the action `{type: 'increment'}` is fired/dispatched like how we check using the redux DevTool?**

Comment: If you have the dev-tools installed then you can see the list of actions getting dispatched. Do you have the extension installed ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [reinspect](https://github.com/troch/reinspect), if you only want to use it during development then [override the webpack resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) using [rescripts](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts)

To do this you need to add the dependencies:

```
yarn add @rescripts/cli -D
yarn add @rescripts/rescript-env -D
yarn add reinspect -D
```

Add a file called `.rescriptsrc.js` to the root of your project with the following content:

```
module.exports = [require.resolve("./.webpack.js")];
```

Then add a file called `.webpack.js` to the root of your project with the following content:

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = (config) => {
  const file =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === `development`
      ? "src/dev/useReducer.js"
      : "src/prod/useReducer.js";
  config.resolve.alias.useReducer = path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    file
  );
  //do the same with your root component (./index.js)
  return config;
};
```

The `dev/useReducer` is:

```
export { useReducer as default } from "reinspect";
```

The `prod/useReducer` is:

```
export { useReducer as default } from "react";
```

In your component(s) you can do the following:

```
import useReducer from "useReducer"; 
...
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
  reducer,
  {
    count: 0,
  },
  undefined,
  "componentName"
);
```

The reason you need a dev and production component is because in production you don't want StateInspector, your root component should look something like this for development:

```
import { StateInspector } from "reinspect";
ReactDOM.render(
  <StateInspector name="App">
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </StateInspector>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And like this for production:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Do not put StateInspector inside React.StrictMode because [there seems to be a bug](https://github.com/troch/reinspect/issues/58)

Answer (score 2):

Just create your own logging function.

```
import { useReducer, useEffect } from "react";

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return { count: state.count + action.payload };
    case "decrement":
      return { count: state.count - action.payload };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

const addLoggingToDispatch = (dispatch, args) => {
  console.log(args);
  dispatch(args);
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { count: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    addLoggingToDispatch(dispatch, { type: "increment", payload: "data" });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit new-moon-0g3zd]